# Override a call to a base class in C++ without using a virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

Given a base class `A`, with the `A::get` and `A::add` functions defined.

```
class A { 
public:
  int get() { return 3; }
  int add() {
    return get() + get();
  }
};
```

Note that `A::add` calls `A::get`. Is there a way a derived class `B` can call `A::add` but use it's own `B::get` function? Something like:

```
class B : public A {
  int get() { return 7; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  A foo;
  std::cout << foo.add() << std::endl;

  B bar;
  std::cout << bar.add() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Where the expected output is `14` not `6` in the second case. If had control over `A`, I could make `::get` a virtual function and each derived class could implement it as needed. However, lets assume that `A` is immutable - how do I call the correct `::get`?

Comment: override add() in B and call { return A::get() + A::get(); }

Comment: @RockyTriton you don't override a non-virtual function, you hide it.

Comment: What do you mean by "assume that A is immutable"? That doesn't make sense in the context you use it (at least not for C++).

Comment: @RobK In the context of this question: `A` is immutable in that I'm not allowed to edit the code for external reasons. I guess it would be more correct to consider that the code to `A` is _frozen_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible: imagine that `A` is compiled separately and given to you as a pre-compiled library to see why.

Since `A::get` is not virtual, the compiler inserts a call straight to `A::get`, without any indirection through [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), into its output for `A::add`. Moreover, the compiler could even inline the call if it chooses to do so, "baking in" the return of `3` into its output.

Comment: Good point - I see now why this isn't possible. Naïve question: Say we can modify `A`, can `A::get` be made virtual but still use a default method if its never overridden?

Comment: That's the very definition of virtual, @Hooked. Maybe you're confusing it with *pure* (or *abstract*), where there is no "default method." If `A::get` isn't pure, then it will be called whenever it has not been overridden.

Comment: @Hooked Absolutely! Marking `A::get` virtual will get the job done, because instead of calling `A::get` directly the compiler will be forced to insert an indirect call through vtable's entry for `get`. The default entry would remain `A`'s implementation, but `B` would get a chance to replace it with its own implementation.

Comment: @RobKennedy I guess I've only ever implemented a virtual function as _pure_ and not known any other way (or realized what the difference was). Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
class B : public A {
  int get() { return 7; }
  int add() {
    return get() + get();
  }
};
```

That's because when you define `A::add()` as

```
int add() {
  return get() + get();
}
```

**you tell the compiler** to use `A::get()`, because it's not `virtual`, and the call is resolved statically.

Important: if you need to do this, you're probably doing something wrong. Most likely, the author of `A` wanted it to behave in some way, and didn't want `get` or `add` to be virtual. This is just a workaround.

Comment: Sadly, I am the author of both `A` and `B` (I am learning more complicated programming techniques as I go). `A::add` is a large complicated energy calculation for a Monte-Carlo simulation. I have simulations that use `A` already and I'd rather not unintentionally modify its behavior. I don't want to duplicate the code for `add`, I just want to change a small part of the internals.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is immutable, you can create a proxy to `A` that defines the virtual interfaces you need.

```
class A_Proxy : public A {
public:
  virtual ~A_Proxy () {}
  virtual int get() { return A::get(); }
  int add() { return get() + get(); }
};
```

Now, you can change `B` to inherit from `A_Proxy` instead, and get the behavior you want.

**Edit:** Based on your comment to Luchian, I think a template method would be better suited for you. You modify `A` so that your `add` routine retrieves values from a template method parameter. The, you create a new `add` that calls the templated version with a template parameter that matches the original behavior.

```
class A {
public:
  int get() { return 3; }

  template <typename GET>
  int add(const GET &g) { return g(this) + g(this); }

  struct DefaultGet {
    int operator () (A *p) const { return p->get(); }
  };

  int add() { return add(DefaultGet()); }
};
```

Then, `B` calls the templated `add` routine passing in a get parameter that it wants to have.

```
class B : public A {
public:
  struct BGet {
    int operator () (A *) const { return 7; }
  };
  int add() { return A::add(BGet()); }
};
```